# How to get a dictionary with mean for every type of attribute

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working on a project where I have a dataset of a lot of values that have an attribute called `grade`.
There are `5700` different grades and I need to get a mean for every single one of them, as I need to access them later on, `dictionary` would be the preferred type. How can this be done without using so many `if` statements?

Example:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 2, 5]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df2
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  2  5
```

No I need a mean for every unique attribute in row `b`. So for example, in this case for every `b` with value of `2`, mean is `4`, for every attribute with value of `5`, it is `6`, etc

Comment: Please provide (minimal) examples of both input and desired output.

Comment: Try using pandas `DataFrame` object, with the already prepared `mean()` function on a column.

Comment: @SimonFromme example added

Comment: @OmerM25 I cannot do that as I do not only need 1 mean, but a mean for every unique attribute in a column b

Comment: Even after your explanations it's not at all understandable what you want. Please provide a full output for your sample input and try to clarify further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in case you want all means for a specific column, say 'b', you can just use groupby and aggregate by `mean`. For example:

```
mean_df = df2.groupby("b").mean()
```

Output:

```
   a  c
b      
2  4  4
5  4  6
```